# Android ScrollView overscroll indicator Issue

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview, overscroll

This is a strange issue I'm having with my Samsung GT-I9003L. I've a ScrollView containing a LinearLayout with different stuff inside (ImageView, Button, EditText, etc.) and it works perfectly when tested in the emulator, both in 2.3.3 and 4.2 versions.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_description"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_camera"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_new_btn_camera" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_gallery"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_new_btn_gallery" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/add_new_name_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="80" />

        [...]
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The thing is that when I test it on my phone, the overscroll indicators (the blue/orange glows) doesn't show at all. I've managed to get them working with this line:

```
ScrollView addNewScroll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
addNewScroll.setOverScrollMode(ScrollView.OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS);
```

But when I reach the top or the end, the glow just "appears", it doesn't animates or fades in.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I would guess that this is because of the UI (TouchWiz?) which Samsung puts in their phones... It somehow overrides Android's default settings

Comment: I wouldn't doubt that. Every manufacturer should follow the standards, but they don't. The problem is that other apps works just fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are having the exact same issue. Overscolling doesn't seem to work on Samsung Galaxy 2 (Touchwiz), but also on HTC One X phones (older HTC's seem to work).

Is suspect that they replaced the ScrollView implementation with their own, maybe for the stretchy scrollbars or something.

Comment: You can grab a copy from ScrollView from AOSP en package it with your app. So you provide your own copy of ScrollView instead of the one provided by the provider.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I'll try that and see what happens. Thanks for the tip!